# lstView.getFirstVisiblePosition() with errors

Tags: android, listview

I'm creating a multi-upload screen with android based on an example I found on the internet. I made some simple modifications that make with whom to each file send it passes to the next one of the list.
I used these simple lines:

```
int n = ImageList.size()-1;
if (position<n) {
   startUpload(position + 1);
}
```

Here is the complete code on the link.

Ex: http://www.thaicreate.com/mobile/android-upload-file-show-items-progressbar-listview.html

More ran into parts. The problem is when it goes to the problem field of the listview automatically and it is not visible on the screen the system stops and it sucks the message and error:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.view.View android.view.View.findViewById (int)' on a null object reference.
```

I already searched the forum and I did not find the solution.

Error occurs in this lines:

```
View v = lstView.getChildAt(position - lstView.getFirstVisiblePosition());
```

**COMPLETE CODE:**

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity  {

    private ListView lstView;
    private Handler handler = new Handler();
    private int counter = 0;
    List <String> ImageList;
    private ProgressBar progress;
    private TextView status;
    private Button btnUpload;
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        /*** Get Images from SDCard ***/
        ImageList = getSD();

        // ListView and imageAdapter
        lstView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1);
        lstView.setAdapter(new ImageAdapter(this));

    }


    private List <String> getSD()
    {
        List <String> it = new ArrayList <String>();
        File f = new File ("/mnt/sdcard/RAIOTOI/photo/");
        File[] files = f.listFiles ();

        for (int i = 0; i <files.length; i++)
        {
            File  file = files[i];
            Log.d("Count",file.getPath());
            it.add (file.getPath());
        }
        return it;
    }

    public class ImageAdapter extends BaseAdapter
    {
        private Context context;

        public ImageAdapter(Context c)
        {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            context = c;
        }

        public int getCount() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return ImageList.size();
        }

        public Object getItem(int position) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return position;
        }

        public long getItemId(int position) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return position;
        }

        public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
                    .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);


            if (convertView == null) {
                convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_column, null);
            }

            status = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.ColStatus);
            btnUpload = (Button) convertView.findViewById(R.id.btnUpload);

            // ColImgName
            TextView txtName = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.ColImgName);
            String strPath = ImageList.get(position).toString();

            // Get File Name
            String fileName = strPath.substring( strPath.lastIndexOf('/')+1, strPath.length() );
            File file = new File(strPath);
            long length = file.length();
            txtName.setPadding(3, 0, 0, 0);
            txtName.setText(fileName + " ("+length/1024+" KB.)");

            // Image Resource
            ImageView imageView = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.ColImgPath);
            imageView.getLayoutParams().height = 110;
            imageView.getLayoutParams().width = 110;
            imageView.setPadding(10, 10, 2, 10);
            imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);
            Bitmap bm = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(strPath);
            imageView.setImageBitmap(bm);


            // ColStatus
            final TextView txtStatus = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.ColStatus);
            txtStatus.setPadding(3, 0, 0, 0);
            txtStatus.setText("...");

            // progressBar
            progress = (ProgressBar) convertView.findViewById(R.id.progressBar);
            progress.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            progress.setPadding(0, 0, 0, 0);

            //btnUpload
            final Button btnUpload = (Button) convertView.findViewById(R.id.btnUpload);
            btnUpload.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
            btnUpload.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    // Upload
                    btnUpload.setEnabled(false);
                    btnUpload.setTextColor(Color.GRAY);
                    startUpload(position);
                }
            });


            return convertView;

        }
    }

    //Upload
    public void startUpload(final int position) {

        Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {

            public void run() {

                handler.post(new Runnable() {
                    public void run() {


                        View v = lstView.getChildAt(position - lstView.getFirstVisiblePosition());

                        // Show ProgressBar
                        ProgressBar progress = (ProgressBar) v.findViewById(R.id.progressBar);
                        progress.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                        // Status
                        status = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.ColStatus);
                        status.setText("Enviando...");

                        new UploadFileAsync().execute(String.valueOf(position));

                    }
                });

            }
        };
        new Thread(runnable).start();
    }


    // Async Upload
    public class UploadFileAsync extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Void> {

        String resServer;
        int position;

        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
        }

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(String... params) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            position = Integer.parseInt(params[0]);

            int bytesRead, bytesAvailable, bufferSize;
            byte[] buffer;
            int maxBufferSize = 1 * 1024 * 1024;
            int resCode = 0;
            String resMessage = "";

            String lineEnd = "\r\n";
            String twoHyphens = "--";
            String boundary =  "*****";

            // File Path
            String strSDPath = ImageList.get(position).toString();

            // Upload to PHP Script
            String strUrlServer = "http://192.168.1.134:8080/up.php";

            try {
                /** Check file on SD Card ***/
                File file = new File(strSDPath);
                if(!file.exists())
                {
                    resServer = "{\"StatusID\":\"0\",\"Error\":\"Please check path on SD Card\"}";
                    return null;
                }

                FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(new File(strSDPath));

                URL url = new URL(strUrlServer);
                HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                conn.setDoInput(true);
                conn.setDoOutput(true);
                conn.setUseCaches(false);
                conn.setRequestMethod("POST");

                conn.setRequestProperty("Connection", "Keep-Alive");
                conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type",
                        "multipart/form-data;boundary=" + boundary);

                DataOutputStream outputStream = new DataOutputStream(conn
                        .getOutputStream());
                outputStream.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + lineEnd);
                outputStream
                        .writeBytes("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"filUpload\";filename=\""
                                + strSDPath + "\"" + lineEnd);
                outputStream.writeBytes(lineEnd);

                bytesAvailable = fileInputStream.available();
                bufferSize = Math.min(bytesAvailable, maxBufferSize);
                buffer = new byte[bufferSize];

                // Read file
                bytesRead = fileInputStream.read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);

                while (bytesRead > 0) {
                    outputStream.write(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
                    bytesAvailable = fileInputStream.available();
                    bufferSize = Math.min(bytesAvailable, maxBufferSize);
                    bytesRead = fileInputStream.read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
                }

                outputStream.writeBytes(lineEnd);
                outputStream.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + twoHyphens + lineEnd);

                // Response Code and  Message
                resCode = conn.getResponseCode();
                if(resCode == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK)
                {
                    InputStream is = conn.getInputStream();
                    ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

                    int read = 0;
                    while ((read = is.read()) != -1) {
                        bos.write(read);
                    }
                    byte[] result = bos.toByteArray();
                    bos.close();

                    resMessage = new String(result);

                }

                Log.d("resCode=",Integer.toString(resCode));
                Log.d("resMessage=",resMessage.toString());

                fileInputStream.close();
                outputStream.flush();
                outputStream.close();

                resServer = resMessage.toString();


            } catch (Exception ex) {
                // Exception handling
                return null;
            }

            return null;
        }

        protected void onPostExecute(Void unused) {
            statusWhenFinish(position,resServer);
        }

    }

    // When UPload Finish
    protected void statusWhenFinish(int position, String resServer) {

        View v = lstView.getChildAt(position - lstView.getFirstVisiblePosition());

        progress = (ProgressBar) v.findViewById(R.id.progressBar);
        // Show ProgressBar
        progress.setVisibility(View.GONE);


        // Status
        status = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.ColStatus);

        /** Get result from Server (Return the JSON Code)
         * StatusID = ? [0=Failed,1=Complete]
         * Error    = ? [On case error return custom error message]
         *
         * Eg Upload Failed = {"StatusID":"0","Error":"Cannot Upload file!"}
         * Eg Upload Complete = {"StatusID":"1","Error":""}
         */

        /*** Default Value ***/
        String strStatusID = "0";
        String strError = "Unknow Status!";

        try {

            JSONObject c = new JSONObject(resServer);
            strStatusID = c.getString("StatusID");
            strError = c.getString("Error");
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        // Prepare Status
        if(strStatusID.equals("0"))
        {
            // When update Failed
            status.setText("FALHOU ("+ strError +")");
            status.setTextColor(Color.RED);

            // Enabled Button again
            btnUpload = (Button) v.findViewById(R.id.btnUpload);
            btnUpload.setText("Repetir");
            btnUpload.setTextColor(Color.RED);
            btnUpload.setEnabled(true);
        }
        else
        {
            status.setText("Envio completo.");
            status.setTextColor(Color.GREEN);

            btnUpload.setEnabled(false);
            btnUpload.setTextColor(Color.GRAY);


            int n = ImageList.size()-1;
            Log.i("IDID", " "+position+" "+n);
            if (position<n) {
                startUpload(position + 1);
            }
        }

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your **lstView** is `null`, make sure you `findViewById()` it first.